# A way to get a music track artwork other than using AVPlayerItems metadata list (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, metadata, avplayeritem, artwork

My app plays tracks from different sources (cloud sources, Documents directory and other) and I see that many tracks don't have artworks in their metadata lists. Can anyone suggest another way to get an artwork for the track? Could there be some kind of API that I could connect to receive artworks over the network for tracks? I'd be very grateful for any advice.